# The type or namespace name 'TestFixtureSetUpAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'NUnit.Framework'

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow

I am creating tests in C# Selenium Specflow.  My framework is fine and builds but when I add a Specflow Feature File and build my project I get the error:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'TestFixtureSetUpAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'NUnit.Framework' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  Olympus D:\Selenium Projects\companyname framework for interviews\Olympus2\Tests\SpecFlowFeature1.feature   3   Active

The version of Specflow installed is v4.0.30319

Why does this error occur?

In my Base class I am using [BeforeScenario()] from TechTalk.SpecFlow;
The error complains about TestFixtureSetUp.  I am not using this attribute anywhere.  This attribute I used to use before from Nunit Framework, this was few years ago before BDD.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try regenerating the c# code behind as a first step by running the custom tool on the feature file, or editing it in some way. Then have a look at the generated file for the Attribute. The name should be TestFixtureSetUpAttribute not TestFixtureSetUpAttributeAttribute. If it is then looks like there is a bug in the file generation tool for that version.

Comment: I have run the custom tool and looked at the cs file of the feature file and it shows [NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureSetUpAttribute()].  I did a search for AttributeAttribute no results was returned.

Comment: I think this is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691940/how-to-configure-specflow-3-0-199-with-nunit-3-11).